# Installing propane tank to gas range with strange copper pipe

Tags: range, propane, copper-tubing

I am replacing a gas range and the gas line that was connected to the previous range doesn't fit into any of the fittings that came with the installation kit or directly into the range (which is how it was setup on the old range).

Here are some images I took of the pipe in question and of it next to the tube that, according to the instructions, I am supposed to connect it to.

Note: I believe that pipe is connected directly to the propane tank on the outside of the kitchen wall.

[image: View of whole pipe]
[image: close up of hose]
[image: hose next to thing it's supposed to connect to]

Why is this like this?
Seeing as though I can't find a setup like this anywhere online, is it safe to say that this isn't up to code?
What do I need to do to connect this pipe to the range properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a 1/4 " ( copper ) male flare to 1/2 " male NPT.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to "go out on a limb" as we used to say and tell you that the shiny flex gas line in the bottom picture is used for natural gas only and the copper line is the one for the propane connection. Any time I hooked up a bottled gas device to a bottled gas source the tubing to the appliance was hard piped or done in flexible copper with flare fittings at the connection point. Compression fittings were never allowed. You will probably have to remove that shiny flex piece up to a threaded fitting, and purchase or add the required fittings to adapt the copper tubing to the device (stove). The copper line looks like 3/8" OD or 1/4" ID (they are the same thing). To complete the installation, you may need someone that can "flare" the copper tubing (that would be a propane dealer or an HVAC company). Stoves in my day, could utilize either propane or natural gas with a minimum of adjustments. Yours is probably set up for natural gas.  If that is the case, nake sure it is changed or adjusted to the fuel you are using. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both ends you show are probably female (you don’t show the detail inside the nut but likely) so you need a coupler.

I would suggest you get a qualified gas fitter to check the installation as you have so many concerns.